# FileListBox OnComplete event

Tags: delphi, listbox

I need to iterate through the files in a FileListBox and find the longest Filename to set some column widths.

I am currently using

```
shFiles.Directory:=shFolders.Directory;
aWid:=0;
for i:=0 to shFiles.Items.Count-1 do
  if Length(shFiles.Items[i]) > aWid then
    aWid:=Length(shFiles.Items[i]);
```

That does what I need, but I am getting problems when the number of files is large and the aWid process begins before the entire FileListBox is full.

I need an Event for "OnComplete" or something to tell me that the FileListBox has finished loading the all of the files into the ListBox so that I can then run the aWid for-next.

How would I go about doing that? Thank you.

Comment: What is an "aWID process" and how is it populating your FileListBox before the above code runs? Is it multi-threaded?

Comment: the OnChange Event is called after internal ReadFileNames

Comment: The "aWid" process is the for-next described above where it gets the max length file name. I just need to know when loading the listbox is complete.

Comment: I had another thought that an "OnSorted" or "OnSortComplete" event would also do as I can set Sorted:=False before passing the Directory and then set Sorted to True after loading. THEN, if I had an OnSorted event, I could run the for-next to get the max length.

Comment: @bummi thank you I will give that a try. I assumed that was only for when the user clicked another file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event you are looking for is `OnChange` it's called after filling the List in `ReadFileNames` calling `Change`. (Unit FileCtrl)

Comment: Thank you, but the OnChange event does not seem to catch all changes. I tried changing the ShowGlyphs and it does not fire the OnChange, but it **does redraw** the list with/without the Glyphs. Can you suggest something that will also catch the list-Refresh as I need to allow for the Glyphs in the Column widths? As I mentioned above, I can force a sort if I can catch an Event for "SortComplete" or similar. I can LockWindowUpdate to prevent flickering with the Refresh.